# create a modal window which is not full screen

Tags: android, ios, window, titanium, modal-dialog

I'm trying to mimic the screen which pops up n an iphone when you click more on a photo, in titanium. I think it is a 'modal window'. I've tried and created a modal window with a few buttons only, for now. Later I will introduce the icons. But the modal window takes up the whole screen and I tried to resize it but that hasn't work.. Any advice on how to reproduce a screen like the one on the left here is very appreciated:
http://9to5mac.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/screen-shot-2012-08-09-at-12-24-18-pm.png
I'd like to try and reproduce something similar to this in Android as well. My original code is below:

```
var ModalWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
            title:'modal window',
            backgroundColor:'black',
            height: "80%",
            width: '200dp'
        });

        var PlayStoreBtn= Titanium.UI.createButton({
            title: 'Play Store',
            top: '10%'
        });

        var youTubeBtn= Titanium.UI.createButton({
            title: 'YouTube',
            top: '20%'
        });

        var facebookBtn= Titanium.UI.createButton({
            title: 'Facebook',
            top: '30%'
        });

        var mySpaceBtn= Titanium.UI.createButton({
            title: 'MySpace',
            top: '40%'
        });

        var twitterBtn= Titanium.UI.createButton({
            title: 'Twitter',
            top: '50%'
        });


        var deleteBtn= Titanium.UI.createButton({
            title: 'Delete',
            top: '60%'
        });

        var cancelBtn= Titanium.UI.createButton({
            title: 'Cancel',
            top: '70%'
        });

        cancelBtn.addEventListener("click", function (e){
            ModalWindow.close();
        })

        ModalWindow.add(PlayStoreBtn);
        ModalWindow.add(youTubeBtn);
        ModalWindow.add(facebookBtn);
        ModalWindow.add(mySpaceBtn);
        ModalWindow.add(twitterBtn);
        ModalWindow.add(deleteBtn);
        ModalWindow.add(cancelBtn);

        ModalWindow.open({modal:true}); 
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a modal window that does not take up the whole screen, don't use the Ti.UI.Window component! Those are way to heavyweight. Use a Ti.UI.View.

Here is a cross-platform view that brings up a modal window, that only takes up 80 of the height, and nests to the bottom of the screen, it also blocks all input on anything below the modal:

```
module.exports = function() {
    var background = Ti.UI.createView({
        backgroundColor : '#000',
        opacity : 0.4,
        width : Ti.UI.FILL,
        height : Ti.UI.FILL
    });
    var container = Ti.UI.createView({
        width : Ti.UI.FILL,
        height : Ti.UI.FILL
    });
    // This is the view that contains all the buttons and shows up
    // It lays on top of the transparent background
    var modal =Ti.UI.createView({
        width : Ti.UI.FILL,
        height : 80%,
        bottom : 0,
        background : '#555,
        borderColor : '#888',
        borderRadius : 8,
        borderWidth : 8,
        ...More styling, maybe even a background image...
    });

    ...Add your buttons to the modal here...

    container.add(background);
    container.add(modal);
    return container;
};
```

Use it like this, assuming its in a file named Modal.js.

```
var Modal = require('Modal');
var modalView = new Modal();
```

Comment: I'm not looking to share any info. I was just using that picture as an example of the type of modal window I would like to implement. The android link you sent me seems to be all java but as I said in the question. I am using the titanium platform.

Comment: If you want that type of modal window then (not for sharing) then you'll have to design it yourself in Photoshop / Illustrator.

Comment: I put an example of making a modal window in the Answer. Try that.

Comment: Ok thanks, I am trying this now. I assume you have to add the modalView to the window?? i.e. moreBtn.addEventListener("click", function (e){
 var Modal = require('Modal');
 var modalView = new Modal();
 win4.add(modalView);
 });

Comment: Got an error: Message- 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {, Source- _filename,_dirname, Titanium, Ti, global, kroll){module.exports = Modal(){ . I don't really know anything about modules so I don't know what your error is exactly

Comment: Oops, sorry, fixed the code, needed to set `module.exports = function()`.

Comment: I added the buttons to the modal where you said to and I set the zIndex of the modal to 500 but none of the buttons are clickable and the modal itself looks to be underneath the other contents of my window

Comment: you said that 'it also blocks all input on anything below the modal'. But the modal is the bottom of the screen. I think things may be the wrong way around? I can press buttons on my main window, but the buttons on the modal are blocked. It should be the other way around. I'll have a cancel button on the modal which will remove the modal view from the window. So the tab bar at the top doesn't need to be active either really. This is a big help, thanks

Comment: below the modal in the z-direction. If this answered your question mark it as answered. Thanks

Comment: But none of the buttons are clickable, the modal is below the window in z-direction somehow. I have a table view in my main window. Each row has a more button. When you click the more button, the modal is added to the window. But I can't click any buttons on the modal

Comment: sorted it. It was the zIndex of the container I needed to change

Comment: I am having a lot of trouble sharing variables between the modal view you created and the main app.js file. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18633370/sharing-global-variables-between-two-js-files maybe because it is a module, there needs to be something else done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a widget tutorial that will show you how to layout your icons.
https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/td/315+-+Using+Alloy+Widgets  At the bottom is the full code.

This code should show you how to swap between views so that you can have more than a single screen of them. https://gist.github.com/joacim-boive/1090202

I've seen better examples of the multiple views, but I couldn't locate one